# Disabling android navigation buttons for disabled children

Tags: android, navigation, accessibility

We’re porting to Android some interactive iOS apps used to teach young children with learning disabilities.  We have hit a major usability issue, because we can't figure out how to disable physical or on-screen navigation buttons (Home and Recent Apps).

Before anyone says “you don’t want to do that”, we fully understand why you would always want these buttons enabled for an able-bodied adult, but these children pose a unique set of accessibility issues.  Specifically:

1. Their fine motor control may be poor - they may inadvertently touch a different area of the screen to the area they intend, or accidentally use more than one finger at once.
2. They may have weak muscle tone and poor physical strength – so e.g. the bottom of the palm of their hand may drop and touch the screen while trying to just use a finger.
3. They struggle to achieve and easily become disheartened or disruptive if they fail.

For instance, a typical 5 year old child with Down syndrome will accidentally drop out of the app they are using as a result of inadvertently touching the Home button: when this happens repeatedly, and the adult teacher or parent has to go back into the app for them repeatedly, the child loses interest and focus.  Another typical scenario is a young child with Autism, who may freak out completely and need physically restraining if this happens while using their favourite app.  Also, many disabled children will try to poke any other button they can find, in search of a response.  In any of these situations, a potentially valuable educational session may have to be completely abandoned.

We're aware of SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE, but these only reduce the visibility of the on-screen buttons until the child touches some other part of the screen, and then they re-appear in a way that’s more distracting than if they were visible all the time.

On iOS there is the “Guided Access” feature that solves this problem trivially.  Can we emulate anything similar on Android?

Comment: +1 for a good question and a valiant cause.

Answer (score 0):

> On iOS there is the “Guided Access” feature that solves this problem trivially.

Guided access appears to be a device setting, not something that developers enable unilaterally themselves, thank heavens.

> Can we emulate anything similar on Android?

There is no similar device setting in stock Android.

You can download the Android source code, modify it as you see fit, build the results into a ROM mod, and install that ROM mod on devices as you see fit.

Or, you can perhaps work with a device manufacturer creating tablets aimed at children to see if either they have already added this capability to their devices, or would be willing to work with you to add such a capability in a future iteration of their devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not really a practicable solution.  Disabled children aren't a big enough market for individual manufacturers to be interested, and in many cases the parents already have one of a wide variety of popular devices.  Also we can't expect them to be willing or confident enough to modify their devices.  So I conclude this is a feature of Android we just have to live with, and that we'll have to warn people about when giving workshop and conference presentations.

Comment: @ColinDean: "Disabled children aren't a big enough market for individual manufacturers to be interested" -- since "individual manufacturers" are willing to ship devices in modest quantities, and since there are a million-plus disabled children worldwide, I beg to differ. Admittedly, in these scenarios, you'd have to supply the OS, with the manufacturer supplying hardware plus device drivers. But if a Spanish teenager can figure out how to custom-design Android phones and get them manufactured (Geeksphone), one would hope that perhaps you could too.